# On url change I want to re render my component how should I do that

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two links that fetches the sample component but when I click on any one of them it gets loaded and when I click on another one it won't re-render only url gets changed. I want to re-render the component on both link clicks. Is there any way to do that??

Comment: have you tried using react router? the tutorial on the github page covers this

Comment: I posted a solution using hooks https://stackoverflow.com/a/69163144/9715289

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was facing similar issue sometime back when I was working on a react project.

You need to use **componentWillReceiveProps** function in your component.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     //call your api and update state with new props
  }
```

**UPDATE**

For react version 16.3+ please use `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
  // update state 
}
```

To make it more clear when your component loads for the first time by calling url www.example.com/content/a  `componentDidMount()` is run.

Now  when you click another link say www.example.com/content/b same component is called but this time prop changes and you can access this new prop under  `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` which you can use to call api and get new data.

Now you can keep a common function say `initializeComponent()` and call it from `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()`

Your router would look something like this:-

```
ReactDOM.render((
     <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/content" component={app}>
        <IndexRoute component={home}/>
        <Route path="/content/:slug" component={component_name} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

So now when you call www.example.com/content/a, **a** would be taken as slug. Within that component if you call www.example.com/content/b , **b** would be taken as slug and would be available as nextProps parameter in componentWillReceiveProps.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: how should i use that nextProps in componentWillReceiveProps function?

Comment: U can go through https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Anyone using on react 17+: `componentWillReceiveProps ` is deprecated and is now called `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops
2. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Answer (score 7):

use location hook.

```
const location = useLocation();

const renderDOM = () => {
 // return your DOM, e.g. <p>hello</p>
}

useEffect(() => {
 // re render your component
 renderDOM();
},[location]);

return (
 <>
 {renderDOM()}
 </>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem myself using a pure function component like this:

```
import { useHistory, Link, BrowserRouter, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function Comp() {
  const history = useHistory()
//  useLocation()
  return (
    <>
      <p>current path is {history.location.pathname}</p>
      <Link to="/abc">click me</Link>
      <Link to="/xyz">click me</Link>
    </>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Comp />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

When you click the links, the URL in the title bar updates but the component does not re-render (i.e. the displayed path doesn't update)

In this case I found the solution is to include a call to `useLocation()` (shown commented out). You don't even need to do anything with the return value; adding this call makes the component magically re-render when ever the location changes.

Note this is with react-router 5.3. react-router 6 is changed beyond recognition so I don't know if the same problem still exists

Comment: It would have been better if you include an example in your answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a full repro

Answer (score 1):

React 16.3+ [discourages the use of `componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

React now recommends moving data updates into `componentDidUpdate` ([source](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data-when-props-change)):

```
// After
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    externalData: null,
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Store prevId in state so we can compare when props change.
    // Clear out previously-loaded data (so we don't render stale stuff).
    if (props.id !== state.prevId) {
      return {
        externalData: null,
        prevId: props.id,
      };
    }

    // No state update necessary
    return null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadAsyncData(this.props.id);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.externalData === null) {
      this._loadAsyncData(this.props.id);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this._asyncRequest) {
      this._asyncRequest.cancel();
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.externalData === null) {
      // Render loading state ...
    } else {
      // Render real UI ...
    }
  }

  _loadAsyncData(id) {
    this._asyncRequest = loadMyAsyncData(id).then(
      externalData => {
        this._asyncRequest = null;
        this.setState({externalData});
      }
    );
  }
}
```