# How do I re-render react components on url change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a route like so:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/question/:title" component={Item} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

The component uses **axios** to fetch data and update the content on the site, this is done in the `componentWillMount` function:

```
componentWillMount(){
        const {title} = this.props.match.params;
        axios.get(server + '/api/question/slug/' + title)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                        question: response.data,
                        loading: false
                    })

                })
    }
```

The problem now is that, let's say I'm on a page "site.com/question/this-is-an-article",
and I use `<Link to="/question/second-article">Second Article</Link>` to navigate, it's like the `componentWillMount` function is not being called so the former content still remains on the page.
How can I make the `componentWillMount` function to run when there is a change in the url?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915066/on-url-change-i-want-to-re-render-my-component-how-should-i-do-that/38916204 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252353/re-render-same-component-on-url-change-in-react/53509329

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use safe life-cycle is preferred [react-lifecycle-methods-diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)

Since you are using `react-router-dom`, you can get your URL via render props like this, refer to document [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history/history-is-mutable)

```
history.location.pathname
```

So you may try to check if url changed in `shouldComponentUpdate` like this

```
shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  return this.props.history.location.pathname !== prevProps.history.location.pathname
}
```

You can add more condition inside of it, or just prevent complex condition via component design adjustment

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` should not be a goto for this; In asker's case, when the `title` is changing - the component is getting newer props for the updated title - only it is not reacting to those updated props.

Methods like `componentDidUpdate`/`componentWillReceiveProps`(if using older version otherwise use UNSAFE aptly)/`getDerivedStateFromProps` are better fitting for updating state based on props.

Comment: @HS That's the reason why those lifecycles are not preferred, since updating state based on props is not recommended, which you may refer to this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props)

Comment: then what you intend to do with checking if the url is changed via `shouldComponentUpdate` in your answer - wont you change the state of mounted component with newer response triggered by a newer 'prop'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `componentDidUpdate` for the axios calling. Necessarily - you want to call the api when title(a prop) parameter change.

You may also try `componentWillReceiveProps`/`UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` for the same.

P.S. - use `componentDidMount` along with above aptly. Look for lifecycle here http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Comment: does 'componentDidUpdate' run on the first time/initial render?

Comment: @Nengakdakup you may check more about life-cycles here - http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/;

Comment: @Nengakdakup - in relation to the answer, it points towards the concern of having axios called as a result of updated props.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any life cycle, (if yes, just use componentDidMount):

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._initHistoryListen();
  }
  _unListen = () => {};
  _initHistoryListen() {
    this._unListen = history.listen((location, action) => {
      const {
        title
      } = this.props.match.params;
      axios.get(server + '/api/question/slug/' + title)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
            question: response.data,
            loading: false
          })

        })
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
     this._unListen()
  }
}
```